# The class 'App\Form\Database_InteractionType' was not found in the chain configured namespaces App\Entity

Tags: php, symfony, namespaces

Hello i can't find the error when i try to delete something out of my database.

It says that my namespace is wrong but i really cant find any issues.

Here is the action im calling

```
   /**
     * @Route("/delete/{id}", name="delete")
     * @param $id
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function deleteById($id)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entries = $em->getRepository(Database_InteractionType::class)->find($id);

        $em->remove($entries);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('show');
    }
```

Here is Entitiy and my Form.
I have been looking at it for 2 hours straight and i cant seem to find the Iusse..

Entity:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\Database_InteractionRepository")
 */
class Database_Interaction
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $question;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $answer;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getQuestion(): ?string
    {
        return $this->question;
    }

    public function setQuestion(string $question): self
    {
        $this->question = $question;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAnswer(): ?string
    {
        return $this->answer;
    }

    public function setAnswer(string $answer): self
    {
        $this->answer = $answer;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

My Form:

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Database_Interaction;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class Database_InteractionType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add(
                'question',
                TextType::class,
                [
                    'attr' => [
                        'placeholder' => 'Enter your Question',
                        'class' => 'form-control'
                    ],
                    'required' => true
                ]
            )
            ->add(
                'answer',
                TextType::class,
                [
                    'required' => true,
                    'attr' => [
                        'class' => 'form-control',
                        'placeholder' => 'Enter your Answer',
                    ]
                ]
            )
            ->add(
                'save',
                SubmitType::class,
                [
                    'attr' => [
                        'class' => 'btn btn-primary'
                    ]
                ]
            )
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Database_Interaction::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

And my Repository if this is to any help..

```
<?php

namespace App\Repository;

use App\Entity\Database_Interaction;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\RegistryInterface;

/**
 * @method Database_Interaction|null find($id, $lockMode = null, $lockVersion = null)
 * @method Database_Interaction|null findOneBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null)
 * @method Database_Interaction[]    findAll()
 * @method Database_Interaction[]    findBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)
 */
class Database_InteractionRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(RegistryInterface $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, Database_Interaction::class);
    }

    /**
     * @param string $id
     * @return Database_Interaction|null
     */
    public function findById(string $id)
    {
        return $this->findOneBy(
            ['id' => $id]
        );
    }

    // /**
    //  * @return SubmitNew[] Returns an array of SubmitNew objects
    //  */
    /*
    public function findByExampleField($value)
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('s')
            ->andWhere('s.exampleField = :val')
            ->setParameter('val', $value)
            ->orderBy('s.id', 'ASC')
            ->setMaxResults(10)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult()
        ;
    }
    */

    /*
    public function findOneBySomeField($value): ?SubmitNew
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('s')
            ->andWhere('s.exampleField = :val')
            ->setParameter('val', $value)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getOneOrNullResult()
        ;
    }
    */
}
```

If anyone could help me out I don't know where to look anymore...

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look closely at this line:

```
$entries = $em->getRepository(Database_InteractionType::class)->find($id);
```

This refers to the form type class(`App\Form\Database_InteractionType`) not your persisted entity class, which lives in `App\Entity` namespace (the namespace it is looking in), this is why the error is produced. Forms do not have a repository, the related entity does.
Try this:

```
$entries = $em->getRepository(Database_Interaction::class)->find($id);
```

Comment: I spent at least 1 hour looking for this.. thank you